# How to load an api response faster and using it in pandas for analysis in django?

Tags: python, django, pandas, performance, api

I am new to django and currently working on a project which includes data analysis using pandas and showing it on a website. Though it is taking about **1 minute** to load on my local server .
How can I do it faster ?

**views.py**

```
def contest_analysis(request,con_id):

#rating change statistics

url = "https://codeforces.com/api/contest.ratingChanges?contestId="+con_id
rating_changes = pd.DataFrame(get_api_response(url))
rating_changes = rating_changes.drop(columns=["contestName", "ratingUpdateTimeSeconds", "contestId"])
rank_mapping(rating_changes)
participants = rating_changes['oldranking'].value_counts().to_dict()
print(participants)

#contest all submissions statistics

url ="https://codeforces.com/api/contest.standings?contestId="+con_id+"&showUnofficial=false"
data = get_api_response(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(data["rows"])
df = df.drop(columns=["points", "successfulHackCount", "unsuccessfulHackCount"])
new_columns=problem_sep(df)
print(new_columns.keys())
problems2 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k, v in new_columns.items()]))
final_dataset = pd.concat([rating_changes, problems2], axis=1)

return render(request,"cheforces/contest_analysis.html",{"p" : con_id,
                                                         "participants" : participants,})
```

**get_api_response function**

```
def get_api_response(url):
try:
    with request.urlopen(url) as response:

        source = response.read()
        data = json.loads(source)
        data = data['result']
        return data    

except:
    raise Http404('Codeforces Handle Not Found!!!')
```

I am using **codeforces** API .

Comment: Run a profiler (or maybe just print some timings) to find out what is taking the longest in your code. I doubt it's Codeforces.

Comment: @AKX yea true it took about 15 sec. I am thinking to save the API response in a csv format so that it can be fetched later on. I have a script that can do it . (https://github.com/Cricsudheer/Codeforces-Contest-Analysis)
Is there a way that i can automate the process . 
Like every night i run some script which creates a csv file on its own in my static files repo

Comment: Look at e.g. `cron`. Also, you might not need Pandas, depending on the analysis you're doing.

Comment: if you are looking at caching and using servers,  CSV will give you all sorts of synchronisation issues.  Especially if you move it to the cloud.  Much better to serialise it in Redis or similar so you have a scalable solution

Comment: Pandas side, can you make a reproducible example of what your data looks like, how much of it there is, and what this `problem_sep` function does